# Font doesn't display correctly on Safari

Tags: css, safari, font-face

I have a displaying problem with the font on Safari. The font looks slitly thicker on some pages than others. I load only normal `font-weight` in the whole website (no bold), using `@font-face`.

Firefox and Chrome seem to display the font the same thickness on every pages.

**Here is my code:**

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Stanley';
  src: url('Stanley-RegularItalic.eot');
  src: url('Stanley-RegularItalic.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('Stanley-RegularItalic.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('Stanley-RegularItalic.woff') format('woff'),
    url('Stanley-RegularItalic.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('Stanley-RegularItalic.svg#Stanley-RegularItalic') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: italic;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Stanley';
  src: url('Stanley-Regular.eot');
  src: url('Stanley-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('Stanley-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('Stanley-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
    url('Stanley-Regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('Stanley-Regular.svg#Stanley-Regular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

**See screenshot of two different pages:**

[image]
[image]

Comment: cuz every browser has a different rending engine, try `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;`

Comment: you need to add a screenshot of the broken fonts ui so that readers can get the clear idea of your problem

Comment: @Hash my problem is that Safari is displaying diffrent thickness of the font according to the page of my site. But only normal `font-weight` is loaded.

Comment: @Krishna9960 I have updated my question!

Answer (score 0):

Give a try, add this to your `font-face`

```
speak: none;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
font-variant: normal;
text-transform: none;
line-height: 1;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
```

Comment: doesn't seem to work… I am wondering if this has something else to do than the `font-weight`. The problem appears only on the page where I have side tabs. Here is the [link](http://temporarygallery.org/do-not-remove-this-folder/?p=38) where the font is normal and this is the [link](http://temporarygallery.org/do-not-remove-this-folder/?page_id=156) where the font appears thinner (the difference is seeable only on Safari).